# How to display the selected collection product image, price, and vender?

Tags: html, collections, shopify, themes, liquid

I am trying to display the selected collection product image, price, and vendor in the shopify website that I am trying to build from scratch. As you can see here in the photo [(IMAGE HERE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP9Yq.png) I was able to display the heading and the description of the collection using this code:

```
  <h2>{{ section.settings.title }}</h2>
  {%- if section.settings.description != blank or section.settings.show_description and section.settings.collection.description != empty -%}
    <div>
      {%- if section.settings.show_description -%}
        {{ section.settings.collection.description }}
      {%- else -%}
        {{ section.settings.description -}}
      {%- endif %}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
```

Now, what I want is to display the image, price, and vendor of the products that is in that collection so that I am gonna be able to style them. What code do I need to use caused I can't find anything useful in the shopify documents. Please, help me with this one.